# How to create a random integer in C without using any standard randomize function, like f.e. rand()?

Tags: c, random

I need to create a random number without using any library functions or complicated mathematics i.e `math.h` library.

How do I do this without using a standard library function?

Comment: @walnut: what if that is the kind of "complicated mathematics" OP so desires to avoid?

Comment: @usr2564301 OP is saying that they cannot use `math.h`: "*i.e. `math.h` library*", not "*e.g. `math.h` library*" and if that was to count as "complicated mathematics", then there will surely be no way of implementing a pseudo-random number generator without it.

Comment: Like using of power functions or sine functions and others which can just be imported and not coded right now. I want to fully code it with only `stdio.h` and nothing else

Comment: For something like a game where the program is taking user input, so its execution time is focused round that, one simple way is to use the value from `clock()` and add that to the value from `time()` at program startup. It should be impossible for the user to fudge it. to Of course, you'll probably need a modulus to range it.

Comment: Yes. I am new to c and I know only python before hand.. Yeah I actually meant rand() and not random()

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use `rand()`? Although it is open to criticism, for many purposes it is fine. If when coding in C you only want to use `stdio.h` you will have to reinvent a lot of wheels...

Comment: Yeah. Its just that in my project I am not allowed to just use library function without doing anything on my own

Comment: Research "Linear Congruential Generator" and write one of your own.

Comment: @rossum thats whay i did... Thanks